# User-friendly error message in PHP

Tags: php

I have three text files containing the same set of error messages in three languages: English, French and German.

I need to extend the exception class so that when something goes wrong, the own exception object will be thrown, such as "throw new My-Exception("English", 4) - then 4th message in English file will be shown.

This is what I made so far:

```
<?php  

class My_Exception extends Exception {  

     function __construct($lang, $errcode) {  
        $this->lang = $lang;  
        $this->errcode = $errcode;  
     }  

   function getMessageMap() {  
        $errors = file('errfiles/'.$this->lang.'.txt'); 

        foreach($errors as $error) {  
            list($key,$value) = implode(',', $errors); 
            $errorArray[$key] = $value; 
        }  
        return $errorArray[$this->errcode];  
    }  

}  

try {  throw new My_Exception('english', 3);  }  
catch (My_Exception $e) { echo $e->getMessageMap();  }  

?>
```

This doesn't work properly. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: why not simply make those error files valid php code, with an array of translations? it'd be more efficient to load that way rather than your "read into array, split values, hunt down needed value, dump everything else"

Comment: What "doesn't work properly" about it?

Comment: @MarkB, Could you explain please what do you mean?

Comment: @Vulcan - it gives me two warnings: file(errfiles/English.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\HW4\index.php on line 11 -but THE FILES ARE IN THE HW4 FOLDER;;; and another one: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\HW4\index.php on line 13

Comment: @Oksana well, the problem you are having is **clearly** explained by those error messages issued by PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of throwing specific exception messages for each language, I would stick to one normal exception. Then, in your application when you catch those errors, you can show an error page for specific languages.  In other words, don't overhaul your application architecture (even in this minor way) for what is ultimately a font-end problem.

Comment: My assignment is to throw an exception, such as: throw new My_Exception("English", 4) and the 4th error message in English.txt will be echoed.

Comment: @Oksana, I would set up a global top-level exception handler, so that if an exception is unhandled, you can display the appropriate message to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have `implode()` and `explode()` mixed up. Assuming your errors.txt file looks like:

```
1,I am error one
2,I am error two
```

You want each `$errors as $error` to thusly `explode(',', '1,I am error one');` as:

```
array("1", "I am error 1")
```

And yes, the `"1"` is a string until you specifically cast it as an `int` using either `(int)$errno` or `intval($errno)`.

PHP is 'loosely typed' and usually does this in the background so you don't have to worry about it, but you *should* worry about it. Otherwise you'll run into the occasional situations where your code does very strange things.

Comment: Good catch - I missed this first time around. Looking at the code again, the $errorArray array should probably be defined ahead of time as well.

Comment: Ahh, that too. At least outside of the `foreach` if not as a class property.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that the error message looks like this:

> file(errfiles/English.txt): failed to open stream

So try using the full path of the error file...

```
$errors = file('C:/xampp/htdocs/HW4/errfiles/'.$this->lang.'.txt');
```

Also can you confirm that the file really does start with a capital "E"?

The second error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\HW4\index.php on line 13

Is because of the first one. Fix that and all is well.

Comment: It could also be a file permission issue.

Comment: That's what I first thought, but I think the error message is different in those cases. It's something about "permission denied" instead of "No such file or directory"